# Условный оператор if в цикле while

Tags: python

Как в данном коде сделать так, чтобы при вводе с клавиатуры `0` данное значение просто пропускалось и цикл повторялся. Вот условие задачи:

> Напишите программу для самоконтроля навыков устного счёта: пользователь вводит 6 целых чисел, после чего программа должна вывести их произведение. Чтобы перемножать числа было не слишком легко, нули не учитывайте. Гарантируется, что не все введённые числа — нули.

```
number = int(input('Введите число\n'))
perem = 0
final = 1
while True:
    if number != 0:
        perem += 1
        final *= number
        number = int(input('\n'))
    else:
        number = int(input('\n'))
    if perem == 6:
        print(final)
```

Пытался это сделать через `else`, но выполнения кода всё равно прекращается.

Comment: *«Как в данном коде сделать так, чтобы при вводе с клавиатуры 0 данное значение просто пропускалось»* - В задаче нет ничего о *пропускании* из ввода, а **игнорировании** при перемножении.

Comment: "Пытался это сделать через else, но выполнения кода всё равно прекращается." - не может такого быть. Выполнение этого кода может прекратиться только одном случае - если введено не целое число.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вы уверены, что через while надо делать? Обычно цикл while используется когда неизвестно количество итераций цикла, а тут по условию строго сказано, что цикл должен выполняться 6 раз. Приведу код при помощи цикла for, на мой взгляд так проще.

```
final = 1
for i in range(6):
    num = int(input())
    if num is not 0:
        final *= num
print(final)
```

Comment: Переменная `i` совсем не употребляется — лучше: `for __ in range(6)`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так.

```
print('Введите число\n')
perem = 0
final = 1
while True:
    number = int(input())
    if number == 0:
        perem += 1
        continue
    if number != 0:
        perem += 1
        final *= number
    if perem == 6:
        print(final)
        final = 1
        perem = 0
```

Либо написать в конце

```
if perem == 6:
    break
```

если программу нужно завершить после одного ответа

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант вот

```
final = 1
i = 0
while i < 6:
    number = int(input('Введите число\n'))
    if number != 0:
        final *= number
        i += 1
print(final)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Вместо `i = 0` `while i < 6:` и `i += 1` можно просто использовать  `for __ in range(6)`.